# Limiting the amount of queries in Accumulo

Tags: java, accumulo

Pls is there a way to get accumulo to limit the amount of scans by users? 
Eg allow only 10 scans per day for another user.

Answer (score 0):

Accumulo has a pluggable interface for [authentication](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-server-base/2.0.0/org/apache/accumulo/server/security/handler/Authenticator.html) and [table permissions](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-server-base/2.0.0/org/apache/accumulo/server/security/handler/PermissionHandler.html) that are called on each user scan. You could implement a custom solution in those.

However, if you're trying to manage resources with that much granularity, you're much better off putting something between your users and Accumulo, rather than let them query Accumulo directly. Accumulo is a pretty low-level application, and not really designed for free-for-all user interaction. Rather, it's designed to fit into a larger architecture for storing indexes of big data.